# How do you find questions you have commented on in the past?

Tags: support

How do you find questions you have commented on in the past?

I need to add more detail or answer some questions I viewed in the past.

I didn't answer the questions but I left comments on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you find them on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3258/vfclists?tab=activity&sort=comments. In general, the link to the page showing the comments left from a user is `<link to the user profile page>?tab=activity&sort=comments`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do some comments get deleted? I clearly remember leaving a comment on one question, but I can't find it any more. I remember because it was an argument on whether the answer given was correct but I can't find the question any more.

How far back do the results go?

Comment: The list shows all the comments you left that have not been deleted, and if the comments have been left for posts that have not been deleted.

Comment: Do comments get deleted without the person who made them being notified? Is it normal practice? I can't find both the comment and the question any more.

Comment: You don't get any notification for deleted comments. If you don't find the post, it means it has been deleted; in that case, the comment is not deleted, but you cannot see it because you cannot see deleted posts.

Comment: Effectively, you have at least a comment for an answer that has been deleted from the user who posted it.

Comment: To be honest I find it rather odd, because I realized that an answer I originally marked as right did not checkout, and I disputed it with the person who answered. It seems the original poster would have no reason to delete, and now that I have found a better answer the question is gone.
Aside from moderators and the OPs do any others have the ability to delete questions?

Comment: In your case, you don't have deleted questions. Closed questions can be deleted by three 10K users, and three 20K users can delete down-voted answers.